# Deploying a Spring Boot 2.0.4 SOAP Web Service on Tomcat

Tags: spring, spring-boot, soap, war, spring-ws

I've got a Spring Boot 2.0.4 SOAP Web Service working as a .jar file. I used the example here: https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/. I'm building it using Maven. I followed the article exactly, so I'll just show the changes I made here.

It generates the WSDL and I'm able to call the service using curl as described in the article.

Now I want to create a WAR file and deploy it on Tomcat 8.5.

I've followed all of the directions for converting a Spring Boot app to a WAR but I'm getting a 404 error when attempting to retrieve the WSDL or call the service.

I've looked at other similar questions here, but none of the proposed solutions appear to work with Spring Boot 2.x.

I followed these steps to convert to a deployable WAR:

Modify my SpringBootApplication class like so:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(Application.class);
    }
}
```

Change the packaging to "war" in pom.xml:

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

Changed the spring-boot-starter-tomcat dependency to "provided" in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

All of the above might have worked on Spring Boot 1.x, but doesn't with Spring Boot 2.x.

I just get a 404 error when trying to reach the WSDL (e.g. using http://localhost:8180/ws/countries.wsdl - note my Tomcat server is running on port 8180).

My only theory is that Spring's dispatcherServlet is intercepting all of the requests and the "messageDispatcherServlet" isn't ever seeing them.

Note the statement in the article: "By naming this bean messageDispatcherServlet, it does not replace Spring Boot’s default DispatcherServlet bean."

But I don't know how to fix that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: As M. Deinum pointed out, I had the wrong URL. This works with
 "http://localhost:8180/spring-boot-soap-example/ws/countries.wsdl". Still having 404 errors with my real application, but I'll see what's different and post a different question if I'm not able to solve it.

Thanks,
Terry

Comment: When deployed to tomcat your URL changes. I doubt that your application is the root application. Your URL should be something like `http://localhost:8180/name-of -app/ws/countries.wsdl`... When deploying it is no longer the root but a separate application in tomcat.

Comment: Thanks, M. Deinum. You're correct. Sorry for the stupid mistake. I am able to fetch the wsdl if I use "http://localhost:8180/spring-boot-soap-example/ws/countries.wsdl". I'm still having trouble with my real application, but now that this is working, I'll see what's different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As M. Denium pointed out above, I was being a bit thick. The URL when deployed on Tomcat is different from the one used when the app runs from the command line. See my edit above. I'm adding this so I can mark this as answered.